# Настройка модального окна bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Когда через js вызываю модальное окно - `modal()`, то оно появляется в начале страницы, т.е. если страницы прокручена вниз, то что бы увидеть окно, нужно прокрутить страницу вверх.

*Помечу что это только на моб. устройствах.*

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3):

В оригинальном бутстрапе все хорошо в этом вопросе. Вероятно стили вашего сайта переопределяют какие-то стили, которые используются в бутстарпе.
Попробуйте через инспектор сравнить все стили, всех тегов окна, у вас на странице и на оригинальном сайте. Думаю вы найдете различия, которые дадут ответ на вопрос.